# iphone - facebook api in ios4

Tags: iphone, facebook

Facebook released new API that works perfectly on iOS4.
The API's that are in older facebook api are no longer working in new api.
I have the experience of integrating facebook api in iphone3 Apps. but now the api's are no more available.

I'd like to post a message the user's wall. How can I do it with latest API. Is there any tutorial. I googled a lot and I couldn't find perfect URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Dominic Dimarco's tutorial [part 1](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api) and [part 2](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the Facebook Connect iOS SDK, download [here](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).